# Scatter plot with color coded value for each points (like a colormesh)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data indexed by two (non linear) keys.
I am trying to create a scatter point of my data with each key on one axis, and a color bar representing the value of my data.

The issue with colormesh is that my data would for example look like, assuming 4 points, (1,10,1st value),(1,20,2nd value),(2,13,3rd value) and (2,14,4th value), so I can not variate each key independently. Also, there are zones with no data that should stay white.

I am new to matplotlib, and I haven't found any function that seem to be able to do this.

I assume trying to create a colorscale by hand by fixing a few value ranges and then doing a scatterplot would work, but it seems inelegant and non precise.

What would be the best approach to this issue, or is there a relevant matplotlib function/option in the library I missed ?

Comment: Please provide an example code and tell us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity I'll assume you can get a list or array of the first key and call it `x`, the second key and call it `y`, and the value and call it `value`.

Assuming this, you can combine seaborn and matplotlib to achieve what you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y, value = np.random.rand(3, 50)
color_map = sns.dark_palette((0.5, 0.75, 0.9), as_cmap=True)

plot_handle, axis = plt.subplots()
scatter_points = axis.scatter(x, y, c=value, cmap=color_map)
plot_handle.colorbar(scatter_points)

# possibly need plt.show() if using interactively
# or else use matplotlib save figure options.
```

This yields the following example plot:

[image: example sns scatter]

You can look at a wide range of color map options from what is available in `sns.palettes` (the ones that allow `as_cmap` are the easiest), including some that don't requiring configuring any color ranges, like `sns.cubehelix_palette`.